Python Cube Root Assignment
I am trying to solve an assignment for my Python class. We are given a program that we must work through in certain designated areas. The first part involved being given a function that would try to find an integer cube root for a number inputed by the user in third function. As for the second, it would approximate that cube root. This second function is what I am stuck on. It looks like this:
def approximate_cube_root(x, epsilon=0.01):
  cube = abs(x)

  # for cube > 1
  if cube > 1: 
    low = cube / 2 #Enter code here
    high = cube #enter code here
  # for cube <= 1
  else:
    low = 0 #Enter code here
    high = 1 #enter code here

  guess = (low + high)/2 # do not convert to int
  guesses = 1

  while abs(guess**3 - cube) > epsilon and low <= high: #enter code here

    if guess**3 < cube:
        low = guess

    else:
        high = guess

    guess = (low + high) / 2
    guesses += 1 #end of code for while loop
  if x < 0: #enter code here

    guess = -guess

  if abs(guess**3 - x) > epsilon:
    print("Couldn't approximate with this precision, please increase epsilon")
    return False

  else:
    print(f"Found root cube as {guess} for {x} after {guesses} guesses")
    return True

Note that anywhere it says "enter code here" or "end of code for while loop" designates where I am to write my code.
As you can see, I did try writing some code for the function, but when calling it with approximate_cube_root(8, 0.01), it only gives me an error since it took too long to run.

You're searching for the cube root of 8 (which is 2) between 4 and 8. 2 isn't between 4 and 8.

Try adding print(low, high, guess) to the while loop so you'll see what it's doing wrong.

Your logic for how to bound your approximation is wrong. In your example, you are trying to find the cube root of 8, but, you initialize the low guess as cube/2, which is 4. You will never be able to get lower than 4, and the actual solution is 2. Ergo, your while loop will never terminate.
I've edited your code to reflect this.
def approximate_cube_root(x, epsilon=0.01):
    cube = abs(x)

    # for cube > 1
    if cube > 1:
        low = 0  # start from zero for cubes greater than 1
        high = cube  # upper bound is the cube itself
    # for cube <= 1
    else:
        low = 0  # start from zero for cubes between 0 and 1
        high = 1  # upper bound is 1

    guess = (low + high) / 2  # do not convert to int
    guesses = 1

    # Use only the difference between guess^3 and cube as   termination condition
    while abs(guess**3 - cube) > epsilon:
        if guess**3 < cube:
            low = guess
        else:
            high = guess

        guess = (low + high) / 2
        guesses += 1  # end of code for while loop

    # Handle negative numbers
    if x < 0:
        guess = -guess

    # Check if the final approximation is within the allowed precision
    if abs(guess**3 - x) > epsilon:
        print("Couldn't approximate with this precision, please increase epsilon")
        return False
    else:
        print(f"Found root cube as {guess} for {x} after {guesses} guesses")
        return True


Yes, this definitely helped a lot. Another commenter also mentioned how I'd never reach anything lower than 4 with my first method. This definitely helped a lot, thank you.

Try removing the first if/else statement and just starting with low=0 and high=cube. This may help.
